# Struggling to find the data of any rocket during a hyperbolic trajectory

Tags: astrophysics, rocket-science

I am trying to represent the hyperbolic trajectory of a rocket to mars, but i am slightly struggling to find a few values i need for it:

- The eccentricity of the hyperbola required to go to mars, the formula i know is ( e=√(1+E*(2h^2/µ), is this right?
- if so then finding the value for E (specific energy) is difficult as it requires me to know the velocity at the periapsis at the orbit and the distance from the periapsis for the body, the formula is=E=1/2*v^2-(r/µ) , how do i find this?

Is there any data for a shuttle or any body in space which has undergone a hyperbolic trajectory?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. A hyperbolic trajectory reaches Mars at high speed, but you then need to lose that speed if you want to land on Mars. Our sister site has questions on the orbital mechanics of hyperbolic trajectories, eg https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15366/38535

Comment: BTW, the potential term is inverted in your specific energy equation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_trajectory may also be helpful